# how to plot ccdf in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a ccdf graph in matlab, this is an example I found:

http://www.mathworks.se/help/comm/ref/comm.ccdfclass.html

I modified it a bit

```
A = fopen('alltimeinterval.txt');
B = fscanf(A,'%f');
hCCDF = comm.CCDF;

[CCDFy,CCDFx]=step(hCCDF,B)
plot(hCCDF)
set(gca,'XScale','log')
```

The array B contains a column of float number, and the graph I got is like this:
[image]

But I want the x and y axis look like this graph:
[image]

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set some style parameters on your axes and plot.  Its pretty simple and explained well in the documentation.

http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/12/19/plotting-with-style/

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html